# How to get 'Monday Date' in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have an Oracle SQL Query, which I am trying to re-write in MySQL.

PS : The dates are just arbitrary here, in the actual scenario I use this custom query inside Tableau where it accepts user defined Dates.The "Reference Start Date"  is being compared to "Start Date".

Part of the Oracle SQL query:

```
CASE WHEN psr.dt_orgn IS NULL THEN NULL 
ELSE
CASE WHEN CAST('2017-05-22' AS DATE) >= CAST('2017-06-22' AS DATE) THEN TRUNC(psr.dt_orgn,'IW')
ELSE TRUNC(psr.dt_orgn + ((CAST('2017-06-22' AS DATE)-CAST('2017-05-22' AS DATE))*(INTERVAL '1' DAY)),'IW')
END
END) week
```

The above uses an existing Calender table in a Database to convert dates into 'Week Start Dates' i.e Monday Date of that Week

MySQL version:

```
 CASE WHEN psr.originated IS NULL THEN NULL 
 ELSE
   CASE WHEN CAST('2017-05-22' AS DATE) >= CAST('2017-06-22' AS DATE) THEN DATE_ADD(psr.originated, 
 INTERVAL - WEEKDAY(psr.originated) DAY)
 ELSE DATE_ADD(psr.originated + ((CAST('2017-06-22'AS DATE) - CAST('2017-05-22' AS DATE)) * (INTERVAL '1' DAY))
 END
 END) week
```

I am using a solution I found to get 'Week Start Date' in MySQL as follows:

```
   DATE_ADD(mydate, INTERVAL(1-DAYOFWEEK(mydate)) DAY)
```

And I am getting error while doing this.
My question is how do I apply the same to the 2nd else condition with the '1 day Interval' in the MySQL query?

Or is there an easier solution to get week start date in MySQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you're asking how to take any arbitrary `DATE` value and return the `DATE` value of the most recent Monday. In Oracle you can use `TRUNC(datestamp, 'W')` to do that.

Here's one way to do it in MySQL:

```
 FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(datestamp) -MOD(TO_DAYS(datestamp) -2, 7))
```

If you wanted the Sunday, you would use

```
 FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(datestamp) -MOD(TO_DAYS(datestamp) -1, 7))
```

I wrote it up here. http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/sql-reporting-time-intervals/

Comment: Thank you! this is more on the lines of what I was looking, will read up your post.

Comment: But just to be sure , the function I listed which does the same in MySQL, should I not be using that ?

Comment: Use your function if you want. You did  ask for an easier solution, which I provided, and which has been proven in production.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the day of a date using the function on MySQL called *dayname()*, for example dayname("2006-04-24") will return you Monday. In this case you only need to put the row that contains your date into the function. After that you can easily compare two dates.

Comment: This operation has to happen on all rows in the table. Also I dont need the Dayname but the actual Monday Date in this case

Comment: @Anusha this answer has given you enough information to be very helpful.  You can use the function in the query and filter out (select) only the Monday result.

Comment: @Grantly  that's the way I am referring to use dayname